# AutoIT ControlGetPos returns the wrong XY position

Tags: automated-tests, autoit

In AutoIT the function ControlGetPos is supposed to return the position of the control (aka button) in the window. I should be able to just add the window position to the get the position of the control on the screen

```
  run("calc")
  WinWaitActive("Calculator")
  $m = WinGetPos('[ACTIVE]')
  $k = ControlGetPos('[ACTIVE]','','Button9')
  $k[0] += $m[0]
  $k[1] += $m[1]
  MouseClick("main",$k[0] + $k[2]/2, $k[1] + $k[3]/2)  ; click middle of button
  Sleep(2000)
  WinClose("Calculator")
  Sleep(2000)
```

but this doesn't work. It click too high, by about 40 pixels. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ControlGetPos returns the position ***relative to the client area*** of the window ignoring the borders and titlebar of the window.

Instead use the ControlGetHandle, and then WinGetPos, as below

```
  run("calc")
  WinWaitActive("Calculator")
  $hc = ControlGetHandle('[ACTIVE]','','Button9')
  $k = WinGetPos($hc)
  MouseClick("main",$k[0] + $k[2]/2, $k[1] + $k[3]/2)  ; click middle of button
  Sleep(2000)
  WinClose("Calculator")
  Sleep(2000)
```

Comment: I apologize @JohnHenckel, it was uncalled for. I think behind my asshole remark that I shouldn't have made I meant to say trust in yourself as you can see it works out pretty well (answered your own questions within an hour) ;)

Comment: it makes you wonder if this isn't just a bug. Why would ControlGetPos ignore the title bar? that is totally unhelpful. Seems to me that this   should be fixed to return the screen location. That would be more consistent with the other api, such as WinGetPos.

Comment: It expects you to get the position yourself. Not a bug, just WinGetPos() + ControlGetPos() :)

Comment: It would nice if you could do that. However WinGetPos() + ControlGetPos() fails to take into account the title bar and window border.

Comment: Trying to help you find multiple ways to get a solution, and hopefully one that best fits your needs. Trying multiple ways to get the resulting output is going to be a good learning experience, and it is how I've gained knowledge into the autoit language :)

Comment: How would you solve the problem using WinGetClientSize?

Comment: Give it a try, I'm not going to do it for you.